# building a boolean dictionary from 2 lists in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, boolean

I'm trying to make a dictionary with values 'True' or 'False' when comparing elements in 2 lists. This is probably a bit basic but I'm new to coding and I don't understand why it always assigns the 'True' value even though I can see its not true:

```
 letters = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z]

 randomData = []

 f = open('randomData.txt', 'r')
 for line in f:
      randomData.append(line.rstrip().split()[0])
 f.close()
```

The 'randomData.txt' file looks like:

```
 A'\t'0003'\t'0025'\t'chr1
 B'\t'0011'\t'0021'\t'chr7
 D'\t'0043'\t'0068'\t'chr3
 F'\t'0101'\t'0119'\t'chr7
```

The randomData list should now look like:

```
 ['A','B','D','F']
```

I tried:

```
 sameLetters = {}

 i=0
 while i < len(letters):
     if letters[i] and randomData:
         #append to dictionary
         sameLetters[letters[i]] = 'True'
     else:
         #append to dictionary
         sameLetters[letters[i]] = 'False'
     i=i+1

 print sameLetters
```

I expected something like:

```
 {'A': 'True', 'B': 'True', 'C': 'False', 'D': 'True', 'E': 'False', 'F': 'True', 'G': 'False', etc
```

Instead all values in the dictionary are 'True'. Can anyone see the problem? Or give any pointers or explanations? Any help would be great, many thanks.

Comment: why use "True" and "False" when you can use `True` and `False`?

Comment: If your lines really contain `A'\t'0003'\t'0025'\t'chr1` then your `randomData` list will have `["A'", "B'", "C'"]` instead, e.g. a letter and a quote character.

Comment: Well because neither randomData nor letters[i] are null, so both return true.

Comment: forgot the ' ' marks around the 'letters' in this post but they are present in my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like:

```
sameLetters = {l: l in randomData for l in letters}
```

Your current attempt doesn't work because you check

```
if letters[i] and randomData:
            # ^ should be in
```

and Python interprets both non-empty strings (`letters[i]`) and non-empty lists (`randomData`) as True.

Also, note that `letters` is already available in Python:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
```

This is a string, but you can iterate through and index a string just like a list, and `in` will still work.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you meant `if letters[i] in randomData`

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense algorithmically to me, however it returns all false

Comment: ah I see now, yes this works, there was a problem with the txt file format! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you only care about *which* letter appears in your random data, so why not use a `set`?

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

randomData = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'A']

appeared = set(ascii_uppercase).intersection(set(randomData))
print appeared
```

And later you can us it like this:

```
char = 'z'
if char in appeared:
    print 'yes'
else:
    print 'no'
```

**EDIT:**

Then how about this:)

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

randomData = ['A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'A']

appeared = set(ascii_uppercase).intersection(set(randomData))

d = dict(zip(ascii_uppercase, (False,) * 26))

for key in appeared:
    d[key] = True

print d
```

Comment: the letters just representations of more complexed data in my actual problem. Thanks anyway though